# How can i remove bytes from start & end of bulk file in python?

Tags: python

I need some code of this step to do batch of mp3 files on python:

1. Open *.mp3.mado
2. Replace 13 bytes after " 49 44 33" <- ( ID3 -> offset 0 )to zero bytes
3. Remove 334 bytes from end of fileS
4. Save files to *.mp3

Comment: The end is easy; the start is impossible without special file-system support. (By "impossible", I mean any modification other than removing trailing bytes requires rewriting the bytes following the bytes to delete to "fill the gap", so to speak.)

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, you are in luck: you don't need to *remove* any bytes; you are *overwriting* a fixed-size portion with zeros, which you *can* do efficiently.

Comment: Is extract bytes from EOF so i need to remove it ^^

Comment: Can you help me for code of this i need it for batch of corrupt mp3 files :(

Answer (score 1):

The key parts are:

1. Opening the file in binary, read/write mode so that you can seek through the file  and overwrite bytes as needed.
2. Positioning the file pointer to define the starting point for a write operation
3. Using `truncate` to remove bytes from the current position to the end of the file.

The loop could be more efficient, rather than repeatedly reading one 3-byte block after another.

---

```
import io

file_names = [...]

ID3_START = b'\x49\x44\x33'
ZEROS = b'\x00' * 13

for fname in file_names:
    with open(fname, 'r+b') as f:
        # Find the ID3 block
        while f.read(3) != ID3_START:
            f.seek(-2, io.SEEK_CUR)

        f.write(ZEROS)

        # Drop the last 334 bytes
        f.seek(-334, io.SEEK_END)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I have one more question that can i use the original file to repair corrupt file like this but is mov file: select 25804 bytes from offset 20 of corrupted files and move the offset 0-20 of original file and add 25804 zeros bytes and merger data from corrupt and save it to mov